# Creating a line on a DrawingCanvas in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to use the Williams objectdraw library (http://eventfuljava.cs.williams.edu/library/objectdrawJavadocV1.1.2/index.html) to make a line on my drawing canvas. I am very new to Java and am unsure whether I am setting it up correctly. Attached is a screenshot of what happens when I run the code. 
[image: applet not initialized?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extended WindowController,i think you are suppose to extend **Applet**..
http://spot.colorado.edu/~cathyb/hiapplet.html have a look at this page it will be useful.